# React / React Native UI user post like/dislike problem

Tags: reactjs, react-native, user-interface, post, frontend

So, I should start by saying that my backend code works just fine. That is, when the user likes or dislikes a post, it is added to the correct likes array in MongoDB that is associated with that particular post.

My problem is on the frontend UI. I don't mean to throw a bunch of code at you, but I'm including both frontend end fetch requests below. The UseEffect gets all posts from every user and displays them on the page. The `const likePost` handles the likes/dislikes. Note: I've created context with `AsyncStorage.getItem('user')`, but I'm not sure if there's something more that I need to do.

Feed.js

```
const likePost = (id)=>{
  AsyncStorage.getItem('user')
  .then(async (value) => {
  fetch('http://10.0.2.2:3000/like',{
      method:"PUT",
      headers:{
          "Content-Type":"application/json",
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + JSON.parse(value).token
      },
      body:JSON.stringify({    
        postId: id
      })
  }).then(res=>res.json())
  .then(result=>{
           console.log(result)
           
           const newData = data.map(item=>{
            if(item._id == result._id){
              return result
            } else{
              return item
            }
           })
           setData(newData)
           
  }).catch(err=>{
      console.log(err)
  })
  })
 }
```

Below is the return. It is here where I think the problem is. Note: I've included 3 comments within the code below that elaborate on what you're seeing.

```
return(
  <View style={styles.container}>
    
    {
         data.map(( item )=>{

         
          
             return(
              <View style={styles.container2} key={item._id}>

                

              {/* below, however, is the likes ui display which toggles just fine when the user pushes the <LikeButton />, 
              but it shows that the user is liking all of the posts on the page instead of just the one post */}

        {
          
          isLiked
             
             ?
             <View style={styles.isLiked} key={item.likes._id}>
                <LikeButton onPress={()=>{
                likeFunctionsCombined()
                }} />
   
                  <Text style={styles.likeCount} >{item.likes.length + 1}</Text>
            </View>
             :
             <View style={styles.notLiked} key={item.likes._id}>
              <LikeButton onPress={()=>{
              unlikeFunctionsCombined()
              }} />
              
             </View>

          }



              </View>
             )
             })
            }
</View>
 )
```

Again, I wanna re-iterate that in the MongoDB collection, the likes go to the correct post, and they disappear like they should when the user dislikes. The problem is all on the front end.

Imagine that the front end screen has 3 posts: Post A, Post B, Post C.

When a user likes/dislikes Post B, it's showing that they like/dislike all the posts. But on the backend, everything happens like it's supposed to.

---

So, what I'm getting is {*user clicks Post B like button*}: Post A (liked), Post B (liked), Post C (liked)

What I want is {*user clicks Post B like button*}: Post A, Post B (liked), Post C

---

I'm wondering what needs to be changed on the front end. I can edit this to include backend code if need be.

Comment: Could you please further reduce the code to the minimal part that is not working for you ? at the moment its even hard to understand what is the problem. 
I do see, however, that what determines whether a post is displayed as liked is "isLiked" which is not seen within the "map" argument. which is probably wrong, because its value should be calculated per-post and not per page

Comment: Gal, I think you're correct. Could you show me what that might look like? I'm reducing the code now.

Comment: how do you know if the current user liked a certain post or not ? I don't see such property in your data.

Comment: At the start of likePost you'll see ```AsyncStorage.getItem('user')```

Comment: yes, but how 'user' stores your likes posts.